# Submit an form with WYSIWYG Editors via AJAX

Tags: ajax, form, editor

I'm submitting a standard Joomla form via AJAX. Only the apply task is submitted via AJAX:

```
$js = '
    Joomla.submitbutton = function (task) {
        if (task != "cancel") {
            if (!document.formvalidator.isValid(document.adminForm)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (task == "mycontroller.apply") {
            document.adminForm.task.value = task;

            Joomla.request({
                url: document.adminForm.action,
                method: "POST",
                data: new FormData(document.adminForm),
                onSuccess: resp => {
                    Joomla.renderMessages({ "success": [resp] });
                },
                onError: xhr => {
                   Joomla.renderMessages(Joomla.ajaxErrorsMessages(xhr));        
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // submit without ajax
            Joomla.submitform(task);
            return true
        }
    }';

$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->addInlineScript($js, ['name' => 'inline.mystuff'], ['type' => 'module']);
```

Everything works fine. Problem is if the form contains WYSIWYG Editor Element, like TinyMCE.
In that case, content is not getting updated when submitting.

I checked what's happening internally in TinyMCE, but using these functions would not work with other editors. So I came up with this, getting triggered before submitting the form:

```
 Object.values(Joomla.editors.instances).forEach(e => e.instance.hide())
```

It is the same as toggling all editors off, which updates the vanilla form fields and submits the content correctly. After updating, `show()` is used.

That works, but is there a better way of doing this?

As far I have seen, the Joomla.editors functions does not contain any possible way of updating the fields internally, without turning the editors off.